# How to interpret the minimum spanning tree in a fully-connected graph?

Tags: data-visualization, graph-theory, networks

**Can someone explain how the resulting graph is the minimum spanning tree (MST) from the fully-connected undirected graph?**  I don't understand how this is interpreted in this context.

Definition according to Wikipedia:

> A minimum spanning tree (MST) or minimum weight spanning tree is a subset of the edges of a connected, edge-weighted undirected graph that connects all the vertices together, without any cycles and with the minimum possible total edge weight.

- https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minimum_spanning_tree

```py
# Toy Data (Iris dataset, pearson correlation, absolute value)
d = {'sepal_length': {'sepal_length': 1.0, 'sepal_width': 0.11756978413300088, 'petal_length': 0.8717537758865838, 'petal_width': 0.8179411262715758}, 'sepal_width': {'sepal_length': 0.11756978413300088, 'sepal_width': 1.0, 'petal_length': 0.42844010433053864, 'petal_width': 0.3661259325364377}, 'petal_length': {'sepal_length': 0.8717537758865838, 'sepal_width': 0.42844010433053864, 'petal_length': 1.0, 'petal_width': 0.962865431402796}, 'petal_width': {'sepal_length': 0.8179411262715758, 'sepal_width': 0.3661259325364377, 'petal_length': 0.962865431402796, 'petal_width': 1.0}}
g = nx.from_pandas_adjacency(pd.DataFrame(d))

# Remove self-loops
g.remove_edges_from(nx.selfloop_edges(g))

# Graph
print(g.edges(data=True))
# [('sepal_length', 'sepal_width', {'weight': 0.11756978413300088}), ('sepal_length', 'petal_length', {'weight': 0.8717537758865838}), ('sepal_length', 'petal_width', {'weight': 0.8179411262715758}), ('sepal_width', 'petal_length', {'weight': 0.42844010433053864}), ('sepal_width', 'petal_width', {'weight': 0.3661259325364377}), ('petal_length', 'petal_width', {'weight': 0.962865431402796})]
```

[image]

```py
# MST
g_mst = nx.minimum_spanning_tree(g)
print(g_mst.edges(data=True))
# [('sepal_length', 'sepal_width', {'weight': 0.11756978413300088}), ('sepal_width', 'petal_width', {'weight': 0.3661259325364377}), ('sepal_width', 'petal_length', {'weight': 0.42844010433053864})]
```

[image]

Comment: MST is a tree-like structure connecting nearest neighbours. It can be interpreted as a (most concise, in overall length) skeleton or a spine of a network.

Comment: @Peter, nearest neighbours not yet entered the tree. The current nearest neighbour between points already in the tree and yet outside of it.

Comment: The fact that these two graphics use two different projections of the points might be confusing you.  If you wish to compare them, draw them using the same projection.  That will still likely distort the distances, so label the edges with the distances so you can understand the effects of that distortion.

Comment: Good call, using the same layout and removing nodes will make it more intuitive.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In this graph, the minimum spanning tree will have three edges (to connect to all vertices without loops). A tree with four edges will not be possible, because it would lead to a loop. A tree with two edges will also not be possible, because it would not connect to all vertices.

Therefore, to find the MST, you have to compare the total weight of all trees with three edges and find the minimum.

[image]

Let's look at all possiblities (with rounded numbers):

- `sepal_width -- petal_length (0.4284) , sepal_width -- petal_width (0.3661) , sepal_width -- sepal_length (0.1176) = 0.9121`
- `sepal_width -- petal_width (0.3661) , petal_width -- petal_length (0.9629) , petal_width -- sepal_length (0.8179) = 2.1469`
- `petal_width -- sepal_length (0.8179), sepal_width -- sepal_length (0.1176) , petal_length -- sepal_length (0.8718) = 1.8073`
- `petal_width -- petal_length (0.9629) , sepal_width -- petal_length (0.4284), petal_length -- sepal_length (0.8718) = 2.2631`
- `sepal_width -- petal_length (0.4284) , sepal_width -- petal_width (0.3661) , petal_width -- sepal_length (0.8179) = 1.6124`
- `sepal_width -- petal_width (0.3661) , petal_width -- sepal_length (0.8179) , petal_length -- sepal_length (0.8718) = 2.0558`
- `petal_width -- sepal_length (0.8179) , petal_length -- sepal_length (0.8718) , sepal_width -- petal_length (0.4284) = 2.1181`
- `petal_length -- sepal_length (0.8718) , sepal_width -- petal_length (0.4284) , sepal_width -- petal_width (0.3661) = 1.6663`
- `petal_length -- sepal_width (0.4284), sepal_width -- sepal_length (0.1176), sepal_length -- petal_width (0.8179) = 1.3639`
- `petal_length -- sepal_width (0.4284), sepal_width -- sepal_length (0.1176), petal_length -- petal_width (0.9629) = 1.5089`
- `petal_width -- sepal_length (0.8179), sepal_width -- sepal_length (0.1176), petal_length -- petal_width (0.9629) = 1.8984`
- `petal_length -- sepal_length (0.8718), sepal_width -- sepal_length (0.1176), petal_length -- petal_width (0.9629) = 1.9523`
- `sepal_width -- petal_width (0.3661), sepal_width -- sepal_length (0.1176), petal_length -- petal_width (0.9629) = 1.4466`
- `sepal_width -- petal_width (0.3661), petal_length -- sepal_length (0.8718), petal_length -- petal_width (0.9629) = 2.2008`
- `sepal_width -- petal_width (0.3661), petal_length -- sepal_length (0.8718), sepal_width -- sepal_length (0.1176) = 1.3555`
- `sepal_width -- petal_length (0.4284), petal_length -- petal_width (0.9629), sepal_length -- petal_width (0.8179) = 2.2092`

The smallest weight of `0.9121` is achieved for the first combination. I.e., this is the tree with the smallest sum over its edges connecting to all vertices.

Comment: Interesting! Ok, so in terms of applications this may need an inverse.  For example, if you wanted to use this as a "clustering" algorithm then you would provide distances and the network.  Is this the appropriate usage? Forgive my ignorance but I'm having trouble wrapping my head around why having the path of smallest edge weights that connect all nodes would be useful (unless the weights were interpreted as distances for clustering).

Comment: @O.rka: So apparently, there are some clustering algorithms based on minimum spanning trees (see, Grygorash et al. "Minimum Spanning Tree Based Clustering Algorithms"). But as the most obvious application for this, I would rather think about power/telecommunication/street grids: assume you would have to lay cables to provide electricity to each house in a city. Obviously your grid would have to reach each house and the total cost (i.e. weight) of the grid should be minimal. The optimal solution for laying these cables is exactly the MST.

Comment: Thank you, that puts it in context!  I’m coming from biology where usually edge weight refers to a stronger connection but your cable example puts it all into perspective.  I could imagine a similar case with metabolism in using the fewest amount of resources. Thanks again